# Extract bounding box and save it as an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, bounding-box

Suppose you have the following image:

[image: Example:]

Now I want to extract each of the independent letters into individual images. Currently, I've recovered the contours and then drew a bounding box, in this case for the character `a`:

[image: Bounding box for the character 'a']

After this, I want to extract each of the boxes (in this case for the letter `a`) and save it to an image file.

Expected result:

[image: Result]

Here's my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('abcd.png')
im[im == 255] = 1
im[im == 0] = 255
im[im == 1] = 0
im2 = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(im2,127,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i in range(0, len(contours)):
    if (i % 2 == 0):
       cnt = contours[i]
       #mask = np.zeros(im2.shape,np.uint8)
       #cv2.drawContours(mask,[cnt],0,255,-1)
       x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
       cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
       cv2.imshow('Features', im)
       cv2.imwrite(str(i)+'.png', im)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The following will give you a single letter

```
letter = im[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```

Comment: When i slice the array, it gets the wrong indices, i.e: The letter 'a' moved, so i'm getting only the  up-right corner, and with the others i get this error:
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data

Comment: I found what was wrong,the dimensions were inverted, i.e: im[y:y+h, x:x+w]

Comment: How could this solution be modified to put draw the green bounding boxes on the original image?

Comment: @Andfoy I need a help about this post ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097703/how-to-find-yellow-box-coordinate-of-an-image .... can u help me??

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach:

- Convert image to grayscale
- Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image
- Find contours
- Iterate through contours and extract ROI using Numpy slicing

---

After finding contours, we use [`cv2.boundingRect()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) to obtain the bounding rectangle coordinates for each letter.

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
```

To extract the ROI, we use Numpy slicing

```
ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

Since we have the bounding rectangle coordinates, we can draw the green bounding boxes

```
cv2.rectangle(copy,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(36,255,12),2)
```

Here's the detected letters

[image]

Here's each saved letter ROI

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
copy = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
    cv2.rectangle(copy,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(36,255,12),2)
    ROI_number += 1

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('copy', copy)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: How can I apply this method to extract images of words instead of alphabets @nathancy ?

Comment: @Raj same process, just perform image processing till you obtain a binary image then you can use this example. It could work with anything, shapes, objects, word clusters, blobs just as long as the foreground object you're trying to extract is different from the background. In image processing, we generally want the desired object to be in white with the background in black

Answer (score 0):

```
        def bounding_box_img(img,bbox):
            x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = bbox
            bbox_obj = img[y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max]
            return bbox_obj

        img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
        cropped_img = bounding_box_img(img,bbox)
        cv2.imshow(cropped_img)
```

this returns cropped image (bounding box)

in this aproach, bounding box coordinates bases on pascal-voc annotation formats like [here](https://albumentations.ai/docs/getting_started/bounding_boxes_augmentation/)