# How to find yellow box coordinate of an Image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image]

In the above Image, there has some yellow boxes for text part.I want to find those yellow box coordinates.

How to find these yellow box coordinate by using python?

Comment: How did the yellow boxes get there in the first place?

Comment: @MarkSetchell by the magic of **Gandalf the white**

Comment: @MarkSetchell I know,what u want to say. I can get the point when I was making the box.. actually boxes are painted in matlab . but Now I have to get those box coordinates in python .

Comment: Wouldn't it be simplest for your matlab code to output the box coordinates as it overlays them on the picture?

Comment: Have you tried to do the detection using OpenCV on Python? Otherwise, you can try to extract the yellow boxes by using a boundary detector on HSV space

Comment: @barny yes, you are r8, boxes are overlaped that is why it is not so easy. to find the perfect coordinates .

Comment: @EdgarAndrésMargffoyTuay yes I was trying by using opencv . Bt didnt get better result. and I don't know boundary detector on HSV space. if U suggest basic code then I can try.

Comment: I suggest you to try this tutorial:http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html#converting-colorspaces , it introduces you to colorspaces transform, after that, you can check http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#contours-getting-started

Comment: okk thanks for helping me. @EdgarAndrésMargffoyTuay

Comment: Try to extract first the yellow bounding boxes, then it should be easy to threshold it and find the contours, each contour has its own properties, such as centroids and moments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139508/discussion-between-sudip-das-and-edgar-andres-margffoy-tuay).